# “Internal Server Error ” on invalid pages

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

Some lines of my htaccess file will be look like as follows

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.images$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I go for a invalid url, so for mydomain.com/blablabla ,it's giving Internal Server Error. Is anything wrong with my .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these conditions right after `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$`

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/%1 -d
```

This checks if the rewritten URI would exist, if it doesn't, it won't do the rewrite, which is causing an internal loop if the URI doesn't exist.

Comment: Can u please write down full code, relating to my snippet, 'Cause I am not very much familiar with .htaccess

Comment: I've tried but some its always showing 404 found , if valid url is given

Comment: Yes, I've done, but its going to 404 error I checked mydomain.com/privacy , but its not giving the expected resuklt

Comment: @duke Don't know then, I put those exact rules in a blank htaccess file under apache and it works perfectly.